# Tiling window manager with multimedia key support out of the box

Tags: keyboard, software-recommendation, window-manager, tiling

I love tiling window managers. I tried [i3wm](https://i3wm.org/) the other day and loved it. However, I spent all day trying to get my multimedia keys to work. They never did. GNOME and Unity both recognize the key presses and perform the appropriate action.

I am using a laptop where I have to hit an <kbd>FN</kbd> key and then the key that I want. There are really only four keys that I care about:

<kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> = touchpad toggle

<kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> = mute sound

<kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> = lower volume

<kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd> = increase volume

I want a tiling windows manager that has all of these keys working out of the box. I am done trying to mess around with config files. I have tried to get them to work and they continue to give me headaches.

Comment: Unity and Gnome have `unity-settings-daemon` and `gnome-settings-daemon` applications, which launch on each login to those environments. Easiest solutions for you would probably to launch one of those daemons manually once you login to your tiling window manager

Comment: How would that work?

Comment: Well, login to `i3wm` , open terminal , and run `gnome-settings-daemon` , then check your keys.

Comment: Do I need to keep GNOME installed? I got rid of unity a while ago.

Comment: I'd say keep it, you never know when you may want to switch back to Gnome. I personally keep multiple environments in case something breaks. But you can remove `gnome-shell` package and check with `apt-cache policy gnome-settings-daemon`. If it says it's still installed - good, if not - you can run `sudo apt-get install gnome-settings-daemon` . Also let me know if this helps and I'll post it as a proper answer. Comments are not for posting solutions

Comment: I tried running `Gnome-Settings-daemon` from i3 and my FN keys continued to do nothing.

Comment: Did you run it exactly as you typed it , with G and S capital ? everything should be lowercase

Comment: I used the tab complete function. The letters were all lower case in the terminal. I messed up the capitalization in my earlier comment.

Comment: OK, let me install `i3` first, play around with it,  and I will get back to you if I find out anything, alright ?

Comment: @Serg Have you figured out the answer to my issue?

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working. I just appended the following to my i3 Config file:

```
# Multimedia Keys
#increase sound volume
bindsym XF86AudioRaiseVolume exec --no-startup-id amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+
#decrease sound volume
bindsym XF86AudioLowerVolume exec --no-startup-id amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%-
# mute sound
bindsym XF86AudioMute exec --no-startup-id pactl set-sink-mute 1 toggle
```